# Remove pagebreak before gridview in printed webpage

Tags: asp.net, css, html-table

When I print a page with a GridView that spans multiple printed pages, the Gridview seems to insert a pagebreak before itself, so that my heading and the Gridview start on seperate pages. I want the heading to be above the Gridview, on the same page. I don't see where or why the pagebreak is inserted.

```
<h3>Heading</h3>                            
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceDATA" CssClass="table table-hover table-condensed" GridLines="None" ShowFooter="True" DataKeyNames="fldUID">
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="fldData" HeaderText="Data" SortExpression="fldData" ReadOnly="True" />
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

When I go to print this the heading is on its own page, and the Gridview spans the next two pages.

I want the heading to be directly before the gridview. This only happens when the Gridview spans more than one page.

Answer (score 0):

I had to set the gridview css to page-break-inside: auto.

```
 .break-me-if-required {
            page-break-inside:auto
        }
```